# Actionscript display image from url

Tags: flash

How do I display an image in ActionScript without using flashdevelop (Im using IntelliJ IDEA)? I would prefer to do it from a url, but embedded is fine too.

Comment: How do you even dare to call yourself a **programmer**? The first thing(s) a coder does is to read / research / develop / test... then ask here for help if not working (showing what you've tried).

Comment: I did! I spent hours looking! I could only find things for flashdevelope.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing related with "flashdevelop" or any IDE. If you want to load image from a URL, create a Loader variable and load your URLRequest.

```
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest("IMAGE URL HERE"));
addChild(imageLoader);
```

Comment: I did this, but it makes the Image WAY TOO BIG! I need it about 50x50 and it made it 200x200.

Comment: Nevermind it turned out the image was just huge in the first place. Bing image viewer had scaled it down so i thought it was smaller.

Comment: @programmer read the online AS3 API manual. A `Loader` is of data type [**displayObject**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) so check the options that are available. For example there is option [**width**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#width) so try... `imageLoader.width = 250;` now then try making it 50 pixels...

Comment: I did. Clearly you've never tried, because everyone knows you can't just do loader.width=50;

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I figured it out. It looks like you do it like this:

```
[Embed(source = "../src/myImage.png")]
private var Bird:Class;
public function Main()
{
    var img:Bitmap = new Bird();
    img.width=10;
    img.height=10;
    addChild(img);
}
```